# How to display 10 recent news from database using Bootstrap?

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I wanted to display 10 recent news from database. I have used LIMIT 10 in sql query to display 10 recent news. I am using bootstrap.

I am getting only 1 news from the database. I know that here I have to use datalist or listview in design. But I don't know how to implement it using Bootstrap.

Default.aspx:

```
 <div class="container">
    <h1 class="main-module-title">Recent <span>News</span></h1>

       <%-- <asp:datalist runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>--%>


              <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="row"> 
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                        <a href="#">                        
                            <asp:Image runat="server" ID="ImgNews" class="img-responsive img-box img-thumbnail"/> 
                        </a>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-9">

                        <h4><a href="#"><asp:Label ID="newsheader" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></a></h4>


                        <p runat="server" style="text-align:justify" id="newscontent"> </p>
                    </div> 
                </div>
                <hr/>


                  </div>

<%--                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:datalist>--%>
    </div>
```

Default.aspx.cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
       MySqlConnection conn = null;
        string newsitem = null;
        if (!(Request.QueryString["newstitle"] == null))
        {
            Page.Header.Title = Request.QueryString["newstitle"] + " - DubaiExporters ";
        }
        else
        {
            Page.Header.Title = "DubaiExporters - Dubai Business News - UAE Exports";

        }


            try
            {

                string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mysqldbeConnectionString"].ToString();

                string newssql = null;



                newssql = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE status = b'1' AND linkstatus = b'1' ORDER BY datepublished DESC LIMIT 10";
                conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(newssql, conn);
               conn.Open();

                MySqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
                if(r.Read())//while(r.Read())
                {
                    newsheader.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(r["newstitle"].ToString().Trim()).ToString();
                    newscontent.InnerHtml = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(r["newsbrief"].ToString().Trim()).ToString();
                    ImgNews.ImageUrl = "~/images/newspictures/" + r["image"].ToString();
                }

            }
           catch (MySqlException ex)
           {


           }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                if (conn != null)
                {
                   conn.Close();
                }
            }






    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you change `while(r.Read())` to `if(r.Read())`?

Comment: @mjwills...right now i am getting only the single item(1 news)....i want 10 news to be populated...

Comment: @john....i was just doing the experiment...when i used if condition,the 1st news got displayed...and when i used while condition,the 10th news from database got displayed....what i want is alll the 10 news to be displayed...

Comment: @chetan The 10th news item got displayed because you looped through each item overwriting the variables so the last item won. You need to use some kind of list.

Comment: yes @john...but how to display all the 10 news?

Comment: @john...you meant to say Datalist or listview?

Comment: I'm not really sure how it works with how you're working with the HTML side of things. With Razor you can loop through a normal `List<>` object in the razor template. Hopefully someone else can give you an answer :)

Comment: hey @chetankambli. I would suggest you to use DataList for this. Create a DataTable in the Page Load event inside IsPostBack check. bind the Datatable to DataList there. You need to build Item Template of DataList and in there you need to Bind the Label , p and Images to your Data using EVAL() expresssion. Let me know if you need sample code for that. Currently you are getting only one news because Page Load is looping all the news and binding the last one to your Labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the below template and bind the DataList to DataSource in the Page Load event inside !Page.IsPOstBack condition

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                        <a href="#">
                            <asp:Image runat="server" ID="ImgNews" class="img-responsive img-box img-thumbnail" ImageUrl='<%# "~/images/newspictures/" + Eval("image")%>' />
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-9">

                        <h4><a href="#">
                            <asp:Label ID="newsheader" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("newstitle") %>'></asp:Label></a></h4>


                        <p runat="server" style="text-align: justify" id="newscontent"><%# Eval("newsbrief") %></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr />


            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
```

Comment: Thank u so much @gagan..:)